# How can I get the current monitor on which a window is present. I'd like to get the name/ id of the output the window is present on

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, display, script

While I was making a script on Linux which manages multiple monitors and windows present on it, I want to have some command 'x' that can output the current screen the window is on so I can put it inside an `if` loop

```
if my_window == Monitor VGA1
    then do
        moveWindow to left screen
else 
    do
        moveWindow to right screen

#this is just an examplet please don't focus too much on it. please.
```

I tried `xdotool` and `xwininfo` but did not find what I wanted.

I am using debian 10 xfce4 xorg.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe `xprop` can lead you somewhere.

Comment: [I tried reading the man page but found nothing useful](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xprop)

Comment: Try running `xprop -spy` on a window, and then move it across the monitors. Please check what properties change. It's only a guess, though. By the way, what window manager/desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I updated my system info. Moving the window from one display output to another had no change unless I also resize it. In which case the cardinals change.